# changing searchBar Placeholder text Alignment to left iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

here is the code for my searchBar

```
self.searchResultsController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Type your word here"
            //dcontroller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

            self.tableVw.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

            return controller

        })()
```

when i click on search bar the code becomes left align but before that it is always scattered

Comment: Check my answer you can do like it

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You can use `whitespace` to achieve this!!

```
  let searchBar: UISearchBar = UISearchBar()  //your searchbar
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search                  "
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: you're welcome..... :)

Comment: No, other way for placeholder alignment?